# postgresql : create table as union select with a serial key

Tags: postgresql, create-table

I am trying to create a dimension table *dim_airport* from a *raw_data* table. The raw table has 2 airportcode columns (origin and destination). I want to get an exhaustive distinct set of all airport codes and create a table with that. In addition, I also need to add a serial key to perform auto increment. I can do this row_number but wanted to find another way to do it.

```
create table DIM_airport (airportkey serial primary key ) 
as 
select distinct originairportcode as airportcode, 
               origairportname as airportname,
               origincityname as city from raw_data
union
select distinct destairportcode, destairportname, destcityname 
from raw_data;
```

If i defined a row_number window function over airportcode it works. I am looking for a solution where it can auto increment directly without explicitly defining the value from row_number()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of "Create table ... As ..." does not allow defining additional columns, it defines **only** columns from the select statement. Of course you can persist by **select**ing a constant as a place holder and establish the column name. Then create a sequence, update the table to set value for the place holder and then a few alter tables to complete the desired definition.  
A much easier way would just be a 2 step process:

1. Create the table.
2. Populate with simple select.

```
create table DIM_airport( airportkey  integer generated always as identity 
                        , airportcode text 
                        , airportname text
                        , city        text
                        , constraint  DIM_airport_pk
                                      primary key (airportkey)
                        ) ;

insert into  DIM_airport(airportcode, airportname, city)
      select originairportcode  
           , origairportname 
           , origincityname
      union 
      select destairportcode  
           , destairportname  
           , destcityname ;
```

You do not need DISTINCT on either select as the UNION itself eliminates duplicates.
See [examples here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e8258888b59711b4b9b1b1577aa74e4b).